# angularJs Factory .then() is not a function

Tags: angularjs, factory

I am using angularJs v1.7

I need to load my object from a factory , This is working very well:

```
$scope.equipe = equipesFactoryLocalStorage.getEquipeMomentanee();
```

Now, I need to add a .then() like that, because i need to do some things afterward the object gets loaded :

```
equipesFactoryLocalStorage.getEquipeMomentanee().then(function(response){
        $scope.equipe = response;

    })
```

AngularJs is providing this error inside the console:

```
TypeError: "equipesFactoryLocalStorage.getEquipeMomentanee(...).then is not a function"
```

i'm struggling since  hours with this, please help me .

THis is my factory :

```
monApp.factory('equipesFactoryLocalStorage',function(){

    var factory = {};

    /* Charger une equipe momentanee */
    factory.getEquipeMomentanee = function(equipe){

        if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("equipe"))!=null){

            var equipe  =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("equipe"));


        }
        else{
            var equipe  =  {};
            equipe.attaquants           = [];
            equipe.ailiers_gauche       = [];
            equipe.attaquants_soutien   = [];
            equipe.ailiers_droits       = [];
            equipe.milieu_gauche        = [];
            equipe.milieu_soutien       = [];
            equipe.milieu_droit         = [];
            equipe.defense_gauche       = [];
            equipe.defense_soutien      = [];
            equipe.defense_droit        = [];
            equipe.liberos              = [];
            equipe.goal                 = [];
            equipe.img                  = "img/new.png";
            equipe.date_creation        = new Date();



        }

        return equipe ;

    }


    return factory
})
```

please help me, i don't understand why .then() is not working, while it is working without .then()
I've tried with angularjs 1.5 , and have the same error .

i've watched several posts about this, no one is working, i 've tried this :

```
   equipesFactoryLocalStorage.getEquipeMomentanee().$promise.then(function(response){
            $scope.equipe = response;

        })
```

It doesnt work either . it is not a double post, it is really not working.

**EDIT : Thank you Frank Modica, it is resolved now :**

I've changed my factory like this (please notice $q) :

```
 monApp.factory('equipesFactoryLocalStorage',function($q){

        var factory = {};

        /* Charger une equipe momentanee */
        factory.getEquipeMomentanee = function(equipe){

            if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("equipe"))!=null){

                var equipe  =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("equipe"));


            }
            else{
                var equipe  =  {};
                equipe.attaquants           = [];
                equipe.ailiers_gauche       = [];
                equipe.attaquants_soutien   = [];
                equipe.ailiers_droits       = [];
                equipe.milieu_gauche        = [];
                equipe.milieu_soutien       = [];
                equipe.milieu_droit         = [];
                equipe.defense_gauche       = [];
                equipe.defense_soutien      = [];
                equipe.defense_droit        = [];
                equipe.liberos              = [];
                equipe.goal                 = [];
                equipe.img                  = "img/new.png";
                equipe.date_creation        = new Date();



            }

            return $q.resolve(equipe);

        }


        return factory
    })
```

And now, it is working nicely,and .then() returns my object correctly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn this into an asynchronous method, you need to return a promise. Inject the `$q` service and do:

```
return $q.resolve(equipe);
```

If you later change this to be an HTTP call, you don't need to manually create the promise. The `$http` service would do it for you, so you could just do:

```
return $http.get(...);
```

However, if you don't need this to be an asynchronous method, you don't need a promise. You could just keep your service as it is, and do:

```
$scope.equipe = equipesFactoryLocalStorage.getEquipeMomentanee();
// Do something else
```

Comment: Thank you, where do i have to add the first line, inside the factory ?

Comment: Do i need to inject the $q service inside the factory ?

Comment: OK, i haven't got the error message any more, thank you !